# Advice azure general practice

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Making my Azure SubscriptionId & TenantId publicly available: is ok in security aspects or not? Is it possible for some one to misuse my Azure subscription just by knowing SubscriptionId & TenantId alone?

Comment: Exposing any information which is not available publicly is a risk. Who knows what security vulnerabilities are there (even if there aren't any now, there might be ones in future). I dont think there can be a definitive answer to this question

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those fields are particularly sensitive, but it is best practice not to expose them. It's similar to why it's best practice to avoid exposing your birthday or mother's maiden name on the Internet. Neither of those pieces of information in and of themselves is particularly private, but combined with other data could potentially lead to security breaches.

Tenant ID and Subscription ID are not  as sensitive as, say, Client Secret or Client ID, but you can query by combining those fields with other fields (such as Tenant ID + Customer ID), and people could theoretically extract more data from them.

It is best practice not to expose them, though not devastating if they are exposed.